# sensor_msgs/JointState on Arduino

Tags: ros, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've got maybe a very noob question. I'm using rosserial on a Arduino One board and I'm trying to stream out the readings from wheel encoders as a sensor_msgs/JointState data structure. The problem is that I can't figure out how to properly push back elements in the data structure and when I try to use push_back() method I get the following error.

> error: request for member ‘push_back’
> in
> ‘wheel_odo.sensor_msgs::JointState::name’,
> which is of non-class type ‘char**’

Can you help me out?
Thanks!

EDIT: here is the code

```
#include <CAN.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SerialCommand.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
std_msgs::String str_msg;

//sensor_msgs::ChannelFloat32 wheel_odo[4];
sensor_msgs::JointState wheel_odo;
char* id = "/myBot";
ros::Publisher sinbot_odometry("sinbot_odometry", &wheel_odo);

SerialCommand serialCommand;

#define CAN_BUS_SPEED 1000  // 1Mbaud

int state = 0;
int pin = LOW;

byte received[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
byte rec [4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

signed long rec_new;


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:

    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

    CAN.begin();
    CAN.baudConfig(CAN_BUS_SPEED);
    CAN.setMode(NORMAL);
    delay(100);
    Serial.begin(115200); //Baudrate Serial connection
    
    wheel_odo.header.frame_id = id;
    wheel_odo.name.push_back(str_msg);
    nh.initNode();
    nh.advertise(sinbot_odometry);
}
```

PS: By the way what I'm trying to do is streaming out the information from 4 wheel encoders using an Arduino One board.
What I would like to have is the following set of information for each wheel:

> [ ros_timestamp, arduino_timestamp,
> encoder_reading]

Considering that I'm not willing to implement my own message, is sensor_msgs/JointState the best solution in my case?

EDIT: Also, using Joint_state data structure as it is done in this link
"answers.ros.org/question/43157/trying-to-use-get-joint-state-with-my-urdf/"
is not working for Arduino and I get

> error: request for member ‘resize’ in
> ‘wheel_odo.sensor_msgs::JointState::position’,
> which is of non-class type ‘float*’

when I try to resize the structure as:

```
wheel_odo.position.resize(7);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185245/sensor_msgs/jointstate-on-arduino/) by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 706 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-07**:
Please update question with the relevant lines that produce the error. It might be difficult without that.

Also look at the API for sensor_msgs::JointState. http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the arduino has far less memory, the message generation for rosserial uses different data structures. In this case, I think it's representing the list of names int the joint state message as a `char**` instead of a `std::vector<std::string>`. You should probably put your joint names in a `char **` and assign it into your joint_states message.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-07-08**:
Can you provide an example of how you would do that?
Thanks!

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-08**:
char *a[] = {"joint_1", "joint_2", "joint_3", "joint_3.2"};

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-07-08**:
The main problem I'm having is how to allocate memory to my joint space data structure. resize() or push_back() methods seems not to be available on Arduino.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-08**:
Yes, resize and push_back are only applicable to c++ containers. So for a regular array of strings/floats you can only use new / malloc, I guess. Of course the array of strings can be directly specified since it won't change.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I got what the problem was. Basically, sensor_msgs classes/structs are defined differently for the ros_lib on Arduino.
I had to specify the size of the message I'm sending, for example by defining variables like 'position_length' as in the following code:

```
sensor_msgs::JointState robot_state;
char *a[] = {"FL", "FR", "BR", "BL"}; // F: Front - B: Back - R: Right - L: Left
float pos[4]; /// stores arduino time
float vel[4];
float eff[4];

ros::Publisher odometry("odo", &robot_state);

SerialCommand serialCommand;

#define CAN_BUS_SPEED 1000  // 1Mbaud

int state = 0;
int pin = LOW;

byte received[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
byte rec [4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

signed long rec_new;


void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
  nh.advertise(odometry);
  
  robot_state.header.frame_id = robot_id;
  robot_state.name_length = 4;
  robot_state.velocity_length = 4;
  robot_state.position_length = 4; /// here used for arduino time
  robot_state.effort_length = 4; /// here used for arduino time

    robot_state.name = a;
    robot_state.position = pos;
    robot_state.velocity = vel;
    robot_state.effort = eff;
```

After that It worked.
Thanks for the help!

---

Originally posted by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) with karma: 706 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahzary](https://answers.ros.org/users/98902/ahzary/) on 2022-03-06**:
thank you, i had the same problem and this solved it.